# <body> to stretch to 100% of content, not browser size

Tags: html, css

I'm currently having an issue trying to make a container extend below the browser window.

I've added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9GKj/

I'm looking for a solution that will extend below the size of the browser when the content is longer than the sidebar, but will still fill the height of the window when there is not much content

```
<div id="menubg"></div>
<div id="menu">
    <div class="sidenav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
         test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
         test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
         test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
         test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />

    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
height:100%;
}

body {
position:relative;
background-color:blue;
}

#container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
background-color:red;
}

#content {
width:1060px;
padding-left:210px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}


#menubg {
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
position:fixed;
left:0px;
top:0px;
bottom:0px; 
width:200px;
}

#menu {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
bottom:0px; 
width:200px;
}

 .sidenav ul {
list-style-type:none;
font-size:large;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
opacity:1;
}

.sidenav a:link, .sidenav a:visited {
display:block;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
padding:10px;
width:180px;
border-bottom:1px solid white;
border-top:1px solid gray;
opacity:1;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
color:#262626;
background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: try `min-height: 100%` on `#content` and `#container`

Answer (score 0):

Change `html, body { height:100% }` to `html, body { height: 100%; min-height:100% }`

[Demo with no content](http://jsfiddle.net/v9GKj/7/)

[Demo with lots of content](http://jsfiddle.net/v9GKj/6/)

Comment: actually, almost there, however now the issue is that if the nav is long, but the content is short, then the red background doesn't fill the whole page - http://jsfiddle.net/gGqL8/

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
margin:0;
background-color:red;
}
```

This will extend the container to fill the browser width always even if the content is less.

You don't need to specify `min-height:100%` for `body` because the body will inherit height based on the children which is the `container`

Comment: Thanks for your help. almost, but I'm struggling to get the site to work correctly in an example where the navigation bar is longer. see here:  jsfiddle.net/gGqL8 the red background doesn't fill the entire page. I imagine im fighting a losing CSS battle as the nav is absolutely positioned